# Laravel 5 - redirect

Tags: laravel-5

I'am studying laravel 5 and I have an error with a **route redirect**.

I have a controller with two functions:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        //Some code
        return view('index.main',compact('someDatas');
    }

    public function update(Request $request) {
        //Some code here
        return redirect(route('main'));
    }
}
```

Here is my route.php

```
Route::get('/', "main\MainController@index") -> name('main');
Route::get('/update', "main\MainController@update") -> name('update');
```

In my main.blade.php view, I have a link with a redirect to an update update route:

```
<a href="{{asset('/update',['new_id_source' => $source -> id])}}">{{$source -> nom}}</a>
```

When I click on the link, I get an error:

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

The URL is **https://127.0.0.1:8000/update**, but when i remove the 's' of HTTPS I'm redirected to the main menu.

I don't understand why this error happens, I have other applications with similar code that work fine.

Thanks for your time and your responses!

Answer (score 0):

This has probably nothing to do with Laravel. When you use HTTPS is tries to use a secure connection. But, you probably do not have a valid certificate for your "localhost" domain. So, you will usually get warnings. I googled your error and found the following: https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/1117296 It probably has something to do with your Anti Virus software.

When you use HTTP it will not try to use a secure connection and not verify de site you are connecting to. Which is the reason it works. You should use HTTP for localhost and HTTPS for production.

So again, this has nothing to do with Laravel or your code. It is something to do with HTTPS SSL and certificates. So try using HTTP instead for local development.

Comment: In my .env files the variable APP_URL is "http://localhost", in my app.php the variable 'url' is "APP_URL, default: http://localhost".
My application is configured by default. should it go to http://localhost no?

Comment: As i said, this has nothing to do with Laravel or its configuration. This has something to do with your webserver (probably nginx in homestead) which is not serving SSL Certificates for your localhost domain (which is not uncommon). Try always using `http://localhost` and NOT `https`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it's working for me.

```
web.php
 Route::match(['get','post'],'/admin/edit_users/{id}','UsersController@EditUser');

user.blade.php
<td><a href="{{ url('/admin/edit_users',$user->id)}}">
                  <i class="icon icon-edit " style="font-size: 20px;color:green;"></i></a></td>

UsersController.php



    public function EditUser(Request $request,$id){
          $user=User::where(['id'=>$id])->first();

      if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data= array('fname' =>$request->input('fname'), 
                  'lname' =>$request->input('lname'),                  
                  'contact' =>$request->input('contact'),

                );

     $upatedata= DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
      if($upatedata){
           return redirect('admin/users')->with('flash_message_success','User has been update Successfully');
      }else{
       return redirect('admin/users')->with('flash_message_error','Incorrect User Data');
      }
      } 
      return view('admin.users.edit_user',compact('user'));
   }
```